# Multiple frame buffer in android

Tags: android

I am working on creating multiple displays on a single screen, i.e., I want to run two different activities simultaneously.
I came to know that, to achieve this requirement we need to change the surfaceflinger code and some hardware properties in the android source. 
Can anybody help me in finding the exact procedure in modifying the surfaceflinger and other parts of the android source in order to get two displays

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run two activities simultaneously just by getting two displays. Only one application/activity can be run at a time on the activity stack.